# jQuerymobile 1.4 filter of list-dividers won't work as in 1.3.1

Tags: jquery-mobile, search, filter

I've got a problem with a jQuerymobile list like the following example from the Demos site:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wm4Ku/
```

I grouped my list with list-dividers and I want, that the list-dividers disappear as well when they don't have any search result included.

This works perfectly out of the box with jQuerymobile 1.3.1 like in fiddle, but won't work with 1.4 
Does anyone has an idea how I can get the same functionality using 1.4?

Thank you already very much guys..!!

Comment: would be awesome if you have a solution for that....!

Comment: push.. really need a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Adding data-hide-dividers="true" will remove dividers when searching.

http://jsfiddle.net/wm4Ku/2/

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-hide-dividers="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filtern"> </ul>
```

Reference to issue on JQM: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6261